# Chrome: No cipher suits incommon

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, encryption, obsolete

This problem only exists in Chrome and I can get to my URL on https://localhost:8443 **without a problem** in Safari, Firefox and IE:

I tried to fix an "obsolete cipher" suite warning in Chrome and therefore removed all cipher suites with SHA1 and MD5 in my Jetty configuration.  These are all cipher suits available which I can see in the DEBUG logging for Jetty.

**However, with chrome I cannot get to the URL because it does not know any of these cipher suites?!**  Why and how can that be fixed?

This is my Jetty (version 8.1.16.v20140903) SSL connector config:

```
  <Call name="addConnector">
     <Arg>
       <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl.SslSelectChannelConnector">
         <Arg>
           <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.http.ssl.SslContextFactory">
             <Set name="keyStore"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default=".." />/web/etc/keystore</Set>
             <Set name="keyStorePassword">OBF:1v2j1uum1xtv1zej1zer1xtn1uvk1v1v</Set>
             <Set name="keyManagerPassword">OBF:1v2j1uum1xtv1zej1zer1xtn1uvk1v1v</Set>
             <Set name="trustStore"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default=".." />/web/etc/keystore</Set>
             <Set name="trustStorePassword">OBF:1v2j1uum1xtv1zej1zer1xtn1uvk1v1v</Set>
             <Set name="protocol">TLSv1.2</Set>
           </New>
         </Arg>
         <Set name="port">8443</Set>
         <Set name="maxIdleTime">30000</Set>
         <Set name="IncludeCipherSuites">
           <Array type="java.lang.String">
             <Item>TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256</Item>
             <Item>TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256</Item>
             <Item>TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256</Item>
             <Item>TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256</Item>
             <Item>TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256</Item>
             <Item>TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256</Item>
             <Item>TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256</Item>
             <Item>TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256</Item>
             <Item>TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256</Item>
             <Item>TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256</Item>
             <Item>TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256</Item>
             <Item>TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256</Item>
             <Item>TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256</Item>
             <Item>TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256</Item>
             <Item>TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256</Item>
             <Item>TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256</Item>
             <Item>TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256</Item>
             <Item>TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256</Item>
             <Item>TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256</Item>
             <Item>TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256</Item>
             <Item>TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256</Item>
             <Item>TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256</Item>
             <Item>TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256</Item>
             <Item>TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256</Item>
            <Item>TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV</Item>
            <Item>TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256</Item>
            <Item>TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA256</Item>
             <Item>TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256</Item>
             <Item>TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256</Item>
             <Item>TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256</Item>
             <Item>TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256</Item>
             <Item>TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256</Item>
             <Item>TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256</Item>
             <Item>TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256</Item>
           </Array>
         </Set>
     <Set name="ExcludeCipherSuites">
       <Array type="java.lang.String">
        <Item>SSL_DH_anon_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5</Item>
        <Item>SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5</Item>
        <Item>TLS_KRB5_WITH_RC4_128_MD5</Item>
        <Item>TLS_KRB5_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_MD5</Item>
        <Item>TLS_KRB5_WITH_DES_CBC_MD5</Item>
        <Item>TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5</Item>
        <Item>TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_DES_CBC_40_MD5</Item>
        <Item>SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_MD5</Item>
        <Item>SSL_DH_anon_WITH_RC4_128_MD5</Item>
        <Item>SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5</Item>
         <Item>TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA</Item>
         <Item>TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA</Item>
         <Item>TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA</Item>
        <Item>TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA</Item>
        <Item>TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA</Item>
        <Item>SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA</Item>
        <Item>TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA</Item>
        <Item>TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA</Item>
        <Item>SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA</Item>
        <Item>SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA</Item>
        <Item>TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA</Item>
        <Item>TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA</Item>
        <Item>TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_RC4_128_SHA</Item>
        <Item>TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA</Item>
        <Item>SSL_DH_anon_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA</Item>
        <Item>TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_NULL_SHA</Item>
        <Item>TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA</Item>
        <Item>SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA</Item>
        <Item>TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_NULL_SHA</Item>
        <Item>TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA</Item>
        <Item>TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_NULL_SHA</Item>
        <Item>SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA</Item>
        <Item>SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA</Item>
        <Item>SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA</Item>
        <Item>SSL_DH_anon_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA</Item>
        <Item>SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA</Item>
        <Item>SSL_DHE_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA</Item>
        <Item>SSL_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA</Item>
        <Item>SSL_DH_anon_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA</Item>
        <Item>TLS_KRB5_WITH_RC4_128_SHA</Item>
        <Item>TLS_KRB5_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA</Item>
        <Item>TLS_KRB5_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA</Item>
        <Item>TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_SHA</Item>
        <Item>LS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_DES_CBC_40_SHA</Item>
         <Item>TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA</Item>
         <Item>TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA</Item>
         <Item>TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA</Item>
         <Item>TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA</Item>
         <Item>TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA</Item>
         <Item>TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA</Item>
         <Item>TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA</Item>
         <Item>TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA</Item>
       </Array>
       </Set>
       </New>
     </Arg>
   </Call>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You removed lots of secure cipher suites in an attempt to get rid of the "obsolete cipher" message but you did not include any of the modern cipher suites, maybe because your server does not support them. At the end you removed too much ciphers so that some clients will not work any more.

- SHA-1 is used as a HMAC in the cipher suites and this usage is not insecure. Insecure is only the use of SHA-1 as a signature for certificates.
- for a description which cipher suites are considered modern by chrome see https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/83831/google-chrome-your-connection-to-website-is-encrypted-with-obsolete-cryptograph. In short: you need [AEAD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authenticated_encryption) ciphers like AES-GCM or ChaCha20-Poly1305 but these might not be supported by your server.

And for an overview which ciphers are supported by the various browsers see [SSLLabs client test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/clients.html).

Comment: Thanks... I am using Jetty as the server. Do the supported cipher suites depend on the version of Jetty or the JDK. I.e. would an upgrade to Jetty 9 work then because the suites listed above seem to be all the server supports,  (Sorry for ignorant questions but I am quite new to this)

Comment: @Jonas: if the JDK does not support the ciphers a new version of Jetty will not help.

Comment: Ok, simply using Java 1.8 solves it because it contains the GCM cipher suites which are considered "modern"  by Google.
Thanks, Steffen, your answer pointed me in the right direction and made me understand  the whole topic a lot better.